MySQL insert query successful but not inserting into database table
I am working on a React/MySQL registration page.  The insert query runs, but is not inserting into the database table.  I am not sure why.
In the backend folder, I have my server.js file:
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "my_db",
});

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const sql = "INSERT INTO login (`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?)";
  const values = [req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.password];
  db.query(sql, [values], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json(data);
  });
});

app.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log("Listening...");
});    

In my frontend folder, I have App.js that looks like this:
import React from "react";
import SignUp from "./SignUp";

function App() {
  return <SignUp></SignUp>;
}

export default App;

And then my SignUp.js file:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function SignUp() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: [event.target.value] });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8081/signup", values)
      .then((res) => console.log("Registered Successfully"))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          name="name"
          className="form-control rounded-0"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      // 2 more inputs for email and password
    </form>
  );
}

export default SignUp;

NPM start is used to run the backend and frontend.
I am using MAMP server which is running phpMyAdmin on localhost:8888
The form is up and running, and when I enter name, email, and password, the console reads "Registered Successfully" but upon refreshing the database, no records were inserted.
I understand that the query can run successfully without inserting anything, but in this case, I'm not sure why the query is not inserting properly.
What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?
Edit
I made the below edit to server.js as suggested by Phil and MatBailie
in the comments below:
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const sql =
    "INSERT INTO login (`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
  const values = [req.body.name, req.body.email, 
req.body.password];
  db.query(sql, values, (err, data) => {
    // if (err) return res.json(err);
    // return res.json(data);
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error in signup", err);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  });
});

I am getting the below Axios error in the console:
POST http://localhost:8081/signup 500 (Internal Server Error)

In the network tab, I am seeing this:

Edit 2
The response section of the Axios error reads the following:


"the console reads 'Registered Successfully'"... that's because you return any errors as 200 Success. Change your backend code to use if (err) return res.status(500).send(err). I would also advise logging any errors in your server-side code so you can be made aware of them

You can also use your browser's dev-tools Network panel to inspect the actual response body

@Phil - I returned a 500 error, the exact same one I posted in the answer provided by Odri below.

Please [edit] your question to provide debugging details. As already mentioned, you can inspect the actual response body in your dev-tools. Ideally you should be logging errors on the server instead of exposing details to the client... if (err) { console.error('Error in signup', err); return res.sendStatus(500); }

Use (?,?,?) rather than (?) and then use values rather than [values]

Finally, DO NOT store plain text passwords in your DB. Use a hashing verification method like bcrypt

@Phil - I made the "values" edit to the question.  And yes, once I can get the data to save into the dB, I will be hashing the passwords.

You seem to be missing any details about the error. Just for debugging purposes, change it to return res.status(500).send(err) and in the dev-tools panel, select the request and then the Response tab. What does it say?

@Phil - I don't have a response tab in the inspector.  I assume you mean within the Axios error.  I edited the question and provided a screenshot of the response.

See that first screenshot where it has tabs "Headers", "Payload", "Preview", "Response", "Initiator" and "Timing"?

ECONNREFUSED seems to be the problem though. Node.js cannot connect to your MySQL server. Are you sure it's running and the credentials are correct?

Probably a duplicate of node.js mysql error: ECONNREFUSED

@Phil - I'm using MAMP, and phpmyadmin is on localhost port 8888.  React is running on port 3000, and App.js is listening on port 8081.  Could it be something with this?  This is frustrating.

What is you MySQL port? You can check that by running this query in your phpmyadmin SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'port';

Turns out the MAMP server was my issue.  After switching to XAMPP, I was able to capture the form data into the database.

This isn't really an answer that will help other readers. The two products you mention do largely the same thing, and both will run the code you have supplied (if they are configured correctly). The real error is likely to be a server side problem (e.g. an unhandled exception) or possibly pointing at the wrong local port (see Phil's suggested duplicate on the ECONNREFUSED error).

try this
const sql = "INSERT INTO login (`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

or
const sql = "INSERT INTO login SET ?";
db.query(sql, request.body, (err, data) => {
   if (err) return res.json(err);
   return res.json(data);
});


Testing........

No luck on either.  The first example ran the query successfully, but nothing was saved in the database.  The second example yielded an an axios error.

While the SET ? method is neat, I wouldn't blindly pass it request.body, at least not without validation
